# Change links in my site depending if there is data in my database

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is that I have a list of links in my website that I want them to change whenever there is a data in my database or not. To be more specific as you can see in the image below
[image]

I have 6 different links but what i want to do is that whenever there is a data in my database in the education table for example for a specific user, I want to automatically change the Add Education to Edit Education. I can do that as you will see in the code below , the part I cant do is that when I have data in the Education table and in any other table then i need to change only to the appropriate link's names and the paths. I cant find the if statement(i guess i am using IF) to do that. Can you help me ?

My database tables :

[image]

HERE IS THE CODE...

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM education WHERE username='$username'"))
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1)
        {
?>
                        <li> <a href="education2.php">Add Education</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_skills.php">Edit Skills</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_portfolio.php">Edit Portfolio</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_work_history.php">Edit Work History</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_text.php">Edit Text</a> </li>
<?php
        }
        elseif($query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE username='$username'"))
        {

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1)


?>
                        <li> <a href="edit_education.php">Edit Education</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="skills2.php">Add Skills</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_portfolio.php">Edit Portfolio</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_work_history.php">Edit Work History</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="edit_text.php">Edit Text</a> </li>
<?php

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: please add your database table and specify if what is added to your database to change what displayed.

Comment: @DanielCheung I didnt get what you said , should i change something in my code or you want to see my database?

Comment: @AmitThakur so what do you suggest to change?

Comment: @niklakis I want to see your structure of the database. I want you to tell me what changes in the database affects the outcome. I want you to type an expected outcome. Please explain these for us to help you.

Comment: @niklakis I said that because i really can't understand this: "*I cant do is that when I have data in the Education table and in any other table then i need to change only to the appropriate link's names and the paths. I cant find the if statement(i guess i am using IF) to do that.*"

Comment: @DanielCheung I edited my question and now you can see the tables in my database. The changes in the database are that if there is a data in the table education for example then the link name will be changed to Edit Education instead of Add education, some things I want to happen to the other links. The links change name depending on if there is data in a table or not

Comment: @AmitThakur that does not work

Comment: @DanielCheung I want to check in every table in my database that if there is a data from a specific user to change the names of links and tha paths. For example if a have data in the education and skills tables then I want the names of the links to be Edit Education and Edit Skills and the other to be Add Portfolio, Add Work History, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change each link individually, you need an individual if for each link.

Also, you shouldn't ever concatenate user data without sanitizing it, or you'll open yourself to SQL injection attacks. You can use  [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or even better, a prepared statement.

The fixed code should be something like this:

```
<?php
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["username"]);
    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM education WHERE username='$username'"))
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1)
        {
?>
                        <li> <a href="education2.php">Add Education</a> </li>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
?>
                        <li> <a href="edit_education.php">Edit Education</a> </li>
<?php
        }
    }
    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE username='$username'"))
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)<1)
        {
?>
                        <li> <a href="skills2.php">Add Skills</a> </li>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
?>
                        <li> <a href="edit_skills.php">Edit Education</a> </li>
<?php
        }
    }
    // Same for the next ones...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is way easier with OO. When the user signs in, you load all their information. Then in your menu you do:

```
<?php
if(empty($user->getEducation())){
   echo '<li> <a href="education2.php">Add Education</a> </li>';
}else{
   echo '<li> <a href="education2.php">Edit Education</a> </li>';
}
...
?>
```

If you wanna stick with procedural, do:

```
<?php
    if(empty($row['Education'])){
       echo '<li> <a href="education2.php">Add Education</a> </li>';
    }else{
       echo '<li> <a href="education2.php">Edit Education</a> </li>';
    }
    ...
?>
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Hello and thanks for your time but can you be please more detailed in your anwser

Comment: Check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this query?

**Mysql:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM education 
    INNER JOIN skills
        ON education.username = skills.username 
    INNER JOIN portfolio
        ON education.username = portfolio.username
WHERE username = $username
/*More INNER JOINs to every tables you have*/
```

This combines all the tables together to query username. To my understanding, this is what you have asked for.

Remove the new lines and use this in your `mysql_query("")`